# Does this metric exist for clustering data based off its similarity matrix?

Tags: clustering, similarities, metric

I'm working with a dataset where all I have is the similarity matrix (with values 0 to 1, 0 being no similarity, 1 being identical). After I assign the labels, I loop through the matrix and, for each pair of points:

1a) if the points are in the same cluster, add (1-similarity(p1, p2)) to a tracker variable. 1b) if the points are in a different cluster, add (similarity(p1, p2)) to a tracker variable.

For 1a, if the points are similar, then the tracker is only incremented a little bit. For 1b, if the points are different, then the tracker is only incremented a little bit. (which means the cluster is doing good.)

However, if the points are different and in the same cluster OR they're similar and in different clusters, then the tracker gets increment by a lot.

In the end, the tracker is normalized by dividing out the size of the similarity matrix. Scores near 0 are "good," while scores near 1 are "bad"

Does this metric for measuring the effectiveness of clustering exist in the literature? Are there any faults with this metric such that it isn't useful in determining cluster effectiveness?

Thank you!

Comment: At first blush, this sounds like a soft rescaling of the Rand index (with all the problems that Rand index carries). As far as problems—sounds like something worth researching empirically by constructing possible corner cases yourself.

Comment: I like the comparison--I believe RAND is supervised, while the one above is unsupervised.